# How to access configurations like a static object in EF

Tags: entity-framework

I have a configuration table in my database and it contains exactly one row.

```
ConfirmedScheduleColor | OverlappedScheduleColor | ColN
```

Currently, I'm retrieving the configuration like this:

```
var db = new SchedulingDbContext();
var config = db.Configurations.FirstOrDefault();
```

It's currently working fine and I can access my configurations and all. The thing is, the code looks awkward since I'm accessing the Configurations `DbSet` as if it contains many records (`FirstOrDefault()`); although actually, it contains only one record. I want to access my configurations like I'm accessing a static object. How to do that in EF?

Comment: Not so awkward, since you might conceivably have different configuration records for dev/test/production or what have you. Have been doing our configuration with a key/value table plus a view for each set of related configuration items; only the views are used in the EF model-first designer. Talk about awkward: there is an EF designer warning for each view because they don't have primary keys. Will be switching to a single, wide table like yours... and using Queryable.Single to enforce the fact that there must be one and only one row (for now) or throw exception. Thanks for the nudge!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could simply add a property to your `DbContext` that returns `Configurations.FirstOrDefault()` and privatize the `DbSet`:

```
public class SchedulingDbContext : DbContext
{
    private DbSet<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }

    public Configuration Configuration
    {
        get
        {
            return Configurations.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a class in my project that has static methods to retrieve config settings. I use the `ConfigurationManager` rather than the database, but you could adapt it to get the setting from wherever you are storing the value.

In my example I have written a GetFromDb method for you that takes a key as parameter but that is because if I was storing my config settings in the database I wouldn't want to add a column every time I needed a new config setting. I would have a table with Key/Value columns. If you are wedded to the single row table then you might want to do without such a method.

```
public class Config
{
    private _ConfirmedScheduleColor;

    public static string ConfirmedScheduleColor 
    {
        get 
        { 
           if(_ConfirmedScheduleColor == null)
              _ConfirmedScheduleColor = GetFromDb("ConfirmedScheduleColor"); 
           return _ConfirmedScheduleColor;
        }
    }

    public static string OverlappedScheduleColor
    {
        get { return GetValue("OverlappedScheduleColor", "Pink"); }
    }

    public static int ColN
    {
        get { return GetValue("ColN", 2); }
    }

    private static string GetFromDb(string key)
    {
        if(key == "ConfirmedScheduleColor")
        {
           var config = db.Configurations.FirstOrDefault();
           return config.ConfirmedScheduleColor;
        }
    }

    private static string GetValue(string key, string defaultValue)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] ?? defaultValue;
    }

    private static string GetValue(string key, int defaultValue)
    {
        int i;
        if(int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key], out i))
           return i;

        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In EF Core you can set the check constraint for the primary key. It enforces that column Id must have value that is equal to 1 which means only one record can exist in table if you have the primary key.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourTable>(e =>
{
   e.HasCheckConstraint("CK_Table_Column", "[Id] = 1");

   e.HasData(...) //optionally add some initial date for Id = 1
});
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The (rather opinion-based) question is how to make code that only fetches one record look better.

Comment: Well I agree with you partly, but the title of a question was "Represent a single-rowed table in EF" so I figured out some people may actually look for the solution how to make table that may only have one record.

Comment: Answers should answer the question, not just the title. It's not uncommon for titles to get edited because (as in this case) they don't cover the question well. I might even do that.

Comment: @GertArnold The question title should definitely be changed as search engines will return results with heading tags that match your search query over smaller paragraph tags.  While I understand this answer doesn't explicitly solve the OP's more detailed question; it solved mine, and I'm glad I didn't have to continue searching.