# Create single-row tables in web2py

Tags: web2py

I have a configuration table in my database that should have exactly one row, very similar to this [question for entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044152/represent-a-single-rowed-table-in-ef).  When the web2py package is installed, the table will be empty, and the user will need to fill in the values before proceeding to the rest of the application.  (BTW, I'm probably misusing web2py but my goal is to create an installable application for a user's PC instead of a shared web application.)

I'm thinking that I can use something similar to @auth.requires_login() to check that my table is populated at the appropriate moments, and create a fairly standard edit page with the add and delete buttons removed.  Mostly, I'm looking to see if anyone's done anything similar before and if there are any pitfalls to watch out for.

Thanks!

Comment: It is mostly the used DBMS, that will take care of your tables. And I know of none, that wont allow more than one row in any given table. That said, it is no problem to write a Web2Py controller that will do that trick. All you have to do is check the row count, and disallow adding rows if the result is >0.